# calculate length of overlapping time intervals

Tags: sas

```
Location Start      End        Diff
A        01:02:00   01:05:00   3
A        01:03:00   01:08:00   5
A        01:04:00   01:11:00   7
B        02:00:00   02:17:00   17
B        02:10:00   02:20:00   10
B        02:11:00   02:15:00   4
```

Ideal Output:

```
Location OverlapTime(Min) OverlapRecords
A        6                3
B        11               3
```

If each time only two records within the same location overlaps, then I can do it via `lag`

```
data want;
set have;
prevend = lag1(End);
if first.location then prevend = .;
if start < prevend then overlap = 1;else overlap = 0;
overlaptime = -(start-prevend);
by location notsorted;
run;

proc sql;
select location, sum(overlaptime), sum(overlap)
from want
group by location;
```

But the thing is, I have so many(unknown) overlapping time intervals within same location. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you advise how you've arrived at your overlap times of 8 and 13?  I can't see it from the data

Comment: @Keith edited. For `A` total is 11-02 = 9. Overlapping total is 3+5+7=15. Overlap = 15-9=6.

Comment: Your definition of overlap is obviously different to mine.  For group A, the 2nd row overlaps the first between 1:03 and 1:05 (2 minutes), the 3rd row overlaps the 1st between 1:04 and 1:05 (1 minute) and the 2nd between 1:04 and 1:08 (4 minutes).  That makes 7 minutes in total

Comment: @keith. Yes. My original purpose is to calculated these "extra" minutes. So For each minute, I have to keep one "copy" of data.

Comment: so which definition do you need to use?  I can see that what you have done is to calculate the difference between the last end and the first start, then subtract that from the sum of the individual differences.  Do you need to account for instances where the 3rd row overlaps with both the 2nd and 1st rows for example (as in my calculation), or just the previous row (as in your calculation effectively)?

Comment: For location with n row, there's at most n-1 overlap for certain minutes. So in previous example, it's my definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution.  There's no need to use the `lag` function, it can be done with the `retain` statement along with `first` and `last`.

```
/* create dummy dataset */
data have;
input Location $ Start :time.  End :time.;
format start end time.;
datalines;
A        01:02:00   01:05:00
A        01:03:00   01:08:00
A        01:04:00   01:11:00
A        01:13:00   01:15:00
B        02:00:00   02:17:00
B        02:10:00   02:20:00
B        02:11:00   02:15:00
C        01:25:00   01:30:00
D        01:45:00   01:50:00
D        01:51:00   01:55:00
;
run;

/* sort data if necessary */
proc sort data = have;
by location start;
run;

/* calculate overlap */
data want;
set have;
by location start; 
retain _stime _etime _gap overlaprecords; /* retain temporary variables from previous row */
if first.location then do; /* reset temporary and new variables at each change in location */
    _stime = start;
    _etime = end;
    _gap = 0;
    _cumul_diff = 0;
    overlaprecords=0;
    end;
_cumul_diff + (end-start); /* calculate cumulative difference between start and end */
if start>_etime then _gap + (start-_etime); /* calculate gap between start time and previous highest end time */
if not first.location and start<_etime then do; /* count number of overlap records */
            if overlaprecords=0 then overlaprecords+2; /* first overlap record gets count of 2 to account for previous record */
            else overlaprecords + 1; 
            end;
if end>_etime then _etime=end; /* update _etime if end is greater than current value */
if last.location then do; /* calculate overlap time when last record for current location is read */
    overlaptime = intck('minute',(_etime-_stime-_gap),_cumul_diff);
    output;
    end;
drop _: start end; /* drop unanted variables */
run;
```

Comment: I've updated my answer to deal with this.  Basically I calculate a cumulative gap and use that in the final calculation

Comment: In your solution, `overlaprecords` always equals to # of obs in a location.

Comment: Right, I see what you mean.  Simple change to the code, however can you advise if you want the first record to be included in the count?  By definition you can only have an overlap if there are multiple records, therefore the first record shouldn't count

Comment: Just edited answer again.  I think it does what you want.  Basically the first record that shows as being an overlap gets a count of 2, otherwise it's incremented by 1.  If that's not right you should be able to work out how to amend it to suit